Any way to deploy NodeJS app that uses Java to Google App Engine?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xsd-schema-validator We're using this package, and it uses Java under the hood.  Is there any way to deploy this app to App Engine? I'm assuming we'll have to switch from Standard to Flexible and write our own Dockerfile?

In deploying your app to App Engine take a look at App Engine deployment.
Also, try adding the dependency (xsd-schema-validator) in package.json. Check Specifying dependencies:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "xsd-schema-validator": "0.9.0"
 }
}

This should automatically install all dependencies declared in your package.json during runtime.

It throws an error because the AppEngine has NodeJS installed, not Java. I don't see any way to have multiple languages installed in AppEngine Standard
